# I want to disable the crypto password when I switch on my laptop

Tags: security

How do I disable the crypto set up password when I switch my laptop, it is not the login password but the one when you power on your pc. please help
I am using os loki

thanks

Answer (score 2):

It requires some effort to do it. A description of how to do it for Ubuntu can be found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/245112/can-i-disable-full-disk-encryption). I think the steps are identical to elementary OS. The fastest way is most likely to backup your files and reinstall.